# DatePicker date input with custom format

Tags: datepicker, format, momentjs, redux-form

I want to stote dates in my state using redux-form. I use react-datepicker. To make the datepicker compatible with my redux-form i write:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

    const MyDatePicker = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          {...input} dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
          selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null}
        />
        {
          touched && error &&
          <span className="error">
            {error}
          </span>
        }
      </div>
    );

    MyDatePicker.propTypes = {
      input: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
      meta: PropTypes.shape().isRequired
    };

    export default MyDatePicker;
```

The problem is that when i choose date i want it to show as DD-MM-YYYY but i want the date to be saved in my state with the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. How to do this? I use the moment's format function but it did not seem to work

Comment: What do you mean it didn't seem to work ? what error you getting or what result you getting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [the value lifecycle methods](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/) that `redux-form` provides for this.

Use `parse` to format the value coming from `react-datepicker` for storage and `format` to parse the value from the store back for `react-datepicker` to present it. Example:

```
function formatDateForInput(storedDate) {
  // the returned value will be available as `input.value`
  return moment(pickedDate).format('right format for your input')
}

function parseDateForStore(pickedDate) {
  // the returned value will be stored in the redux store
  return moment(storedDate).format('desired format for storage')
}

<Field
  component={ MyDatePicker }
  format={ formatDateForInput }
  parse={ parseDateForStore }
/>
```

If this does not work for your, I would recommend checking if you need to put a custom `onChange` handler between the `DatePicker` and `input` prop provided by `redux-form`. Because it could be that the values `DatePicker` is using to call `onChange` are ones that `redux-form` does not understand. Like this:

```
const MyDatePicker = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => {

  const onChange = event => {
    const pickedDate = event.path.to.value;
    input.onChange(pickedDate);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
        selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null}
        onChange={ onChange }
      />
      {
        touched && error &&
        <span className="error">
          {error}
        </span>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

MyDatePicker.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
  meta: PropTypes.shape().isRequired
};

export default MyDatePicker;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the prop dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"

Example :

```
<DatePicker 
    selected={startDate} 
    onChange={date => handleChange(date)} 
    dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If i am understanding correct you just need 2 different formats for same date one on UI and other to save ? `moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')` and `moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')` will give you both formats date.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below props -**mask**, **inputFormat** and **format** - to change the default format to "yyyy-MM-dd" format.
The format code "yyyy-MM-dd" is important, play around this to find the desired format.

Example:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} >
   <DatePicker
      label="SomeDate"
      {...register("details_received_date")}
      mask="____-__-__"
      inputFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
      format="yyyy-MM-dd"
      value={someDate}
      onChange={(newValue) => {setSomeDate(newValue);}}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

This will display in the front end and provide the value as well in the desired format.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

simply use this prop

dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"

"dd" for date,
"MM" for month,
"yyyy" for year

```js
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  placeholderText="Click to select a date"
  dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try this***

inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DatePicker
        label="DatePicker Example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
      />

</LocalizationProvider>
```