# Redux-form and react-datepicker - how to differentiate presented value format in the input and real value format?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-datepicker

I use [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/) and [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/)
It works very nice, and I would like to get it work ideally according to my needs.
I need to show the date in localized format (let's say DD/MM/YYYY), and in the same time save `value` attribute of the input in static format ("YYYY-MM-DD").
I could add a hidden input with such value format, but if it's possible to avoid it using datepicker customization, it would be great!

Thanks for your advice in advance.

UPD:
Take a look on screenshots:

1. This is how it works now (nothing has to be changed here).

[image: DatePicker]

2. And value is synchronized with the locale. I want to keep the locale to present my date in the locale format for the user, and keep the format unchanged ("YYYY-MM-DD" forever) for the back end.

[image: input value attribute]

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko37ry2kmr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `state` and [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) package to have date in several formats.

EDIT: the key thing is redux form. Datepicker is just view that can show exactly what you need. So, what you can do is: change redux form field value (or what you are using) and just have another state field (let's say 'dateForDatepicker') which value you'll pass to datepicker.

GOOD SOLUTION: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42726079/7479959

Comment: igorves, thanks for you comment. I already use moment with locale, it works fine. I actually want to show my date in localized format (and it already works), and keep the value of input in the format which is valid according to our back end. For now, when I set 'selected' attribute of DatePicker component, selected date is shown in the format I need, but the value is saved in the same format! That's wrong for me :)

Comment: so you can save value in two formats using `state`. Use one for field and other for back end

Comment: can you create `codesandbox` or something with example of your code

Comment: hey, this example doesn't help a lot, cause the key thing is `redux form`. Datepicker is just view that can show exactly what you need. So, what you can do is: change redux form `field`  value (or what you are using) and just have another state field (let's say 'dateForDatepicker') which value you'll pass to datepicker.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks igorves, I've already found the proper solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666118/datepicker-date-input-with-custom-format

Comment: yep, exactly. I've added this to answer. can you check it as `correct` one, please, this will help other people if they find this issue. cheers!